# iOS - Detect Push Notifications when the App is terminated by the user

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I have a problem.  When my App is Terminated by the user, push notifications are not detected by the application. The push notification is sent with `content_available = true`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default system behaviour. If you Application is terminated by the user (from the App switcher), *Silent Push Notifications* `(content_available = true)` will not wake the Application, i.e. `Application:didreceiveremotenotification` will not be called.

If you want the user to be notified, do not send a *Silent Push Notification*. Send a normal push notification which will show up in the user's notification tray.

Comment: I will try this... a full minute I will back for tell you if worked

Comment: Hello friend, strangely after having passed the information on content-available = false started to function as you said, however, even posing as
content-available = true is also working.

Anyway I thank you, although not understand how before did not work and now works both ways!

Comment: @tiagosito Great that it helped you.

Comment: @tiagosito Note: When you send "content-available = somevalue", the factor that determines if the app will be notified or not, is the state of the App. If the App was terminated by the user from the App switcher, the app will not be notified.

Comment: That made me very confusing because I'm forcing the application termination in the switcher and it is being notified in the same way..
I hope it stays that way! (:

Answer (score 1):

That is the way how it works on iOS.

If you app is not running at all, your app receive no push notifications at all. Only if the user swipe over one of your push notifications on the lock screen or the notification center your app will be started and you will be notified that your app was started because of the push message.

If you app is in the background, you actually can handle push notifications by enabling "run in background" support.

I'm talking iOS9 and earlier here. Not sure if the behaviour has been changed in iOS10. But if you are coming from Android then you have to accept that push notification handling works completely different on iOS than on Android.

Comment: Hi, Topper! I need to do something like whatsapp, that even closed it can receive push notifications

Comment: tiagosito, you can receive it but you can't handle it. I dont know about whatsapp, but big services sometimes have personal permissions from apple for hidden api.

Comment: Hi Tropper and user3820674 strangely after having passed the information on content-available = false started to function as 7vikram7 said, however, even posing as content-available = true is also working. Anyway I thank you for help, although not understand how before did not work and now works both ways!

Answer (score 0):

Sending the notification with the content_available as disabled. content_available = 0

The content_available field is used for sending silent push notifications to process in the background and will not display as a notification.

See documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW6

Hope this helps,
DT

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that in your push notification payload you are adding priority:"high". It will ensure that your app will receive a Push Notification in background or closed mode.

`{
        "to" : "/topics/{userId}"
        "content_available":true,
        "priority":"high"
        "notification" : {
                "title": "",
                "body":""
        },
        "data" : {
                //custom key value pairs
        }
}`